# Help needed in writing syntax in android

Tags: java, android, web-services, http, soap

I am facing some problems in Android as I am new to it. I need to know how to write syntax in Android for the below problem.

Problem:
I have a .net web service (`www.somesite.com`). That webserver has an authentication method which requires a user name and a password as a parameter to authenticate. Once I set those things using the authentication method, it will allow me to call the rest of the functionality present in the webserver. I have the source code written in ASP. I want to write the same code in Android.

```
 private MyServerAPI.Service _service;
 _service = new MyServerAPI.Service();

MyServerAPI.DTAuthHeader auth = new MyServerAPI.DTAuthHeader();
auth.Username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyServerAPI.user"];
auth.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyServerAPI.pass"];

_service.DTAuthHeaderValue = auth;
_service.Url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyServerAPI.service"];
```

Basically, I want to write the same thing as the above code in Android.

Answer (score 0):

There's a library for dealing with WebServices called `KSOAP2`. find it [here](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/)

Use it and notice how your server requrires the username and password to be sent.

**UPDATE**
Code Snippet:

```
SoapObject soapRequest = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE, OPERATION_NAME) ;
    soapRequest.addProperty("appName","MyCoolApp" );
    soapRequest.addProperty("sEmail","test@example.com" );
    soapRequest.addProperty("sPassword","test" );
    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new     SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelope.dotNet  = true;
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapRequest);

    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);

    try{
    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
    Object response = soapEnvelope.getResponse();
    Log.d("-----RESPONSE",""+response);
    }catch (Exception exception){
    Log.d("RESPONSE",""+exception.toString());
    }
```

Although I discourage posting whole code here, but since you seem to be in dire trouble, I hope this much helps you.

Or wait a bit I'll blog about it, in detail.

Comment: could you please write a sample snippet and post as it is very urgent for us

Comment: Thanks Sheikh,, Sure i will wait for ur Blog.. Thanks lot :).. i will have a look at ur code.

Comment: Hi, ur code is fine, but one more problem we are facing is, there is an authentication class in the webserver. we are not sure how to create instance of it and call it... do you have any idea?

Comment: Yes, Sheikh definitely i will mark but i have got stuck in the above comment part.. please see is there any way?

Comment: Since I don't have access to your server or that authentication class AND since I'll be outa town for at least 2 days, I am afraid I can't help with that :(

Comment: In General can you tell? like we just want to know how to make object and access in android ?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to depend on 3rd party library then you call also use the inbuild class of android itself.

Here is an function which is used to post data on your webserver along with passing username and password.

```
public void postDataToWeb() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("www.yoursite.com");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Username", "Paresh"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", "PM@Android"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream is = entity.getContent();

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

Now, you are having response in inputstream (in above example, 'is') and you can play with inputstream.

Comment: Hi Paresh, Thanks for your reply, i want to know how to create a instance of a class in Android which is present in .net web service..

Comment: can you help me please i have try this code so can you tell me should i also pass parameter of Content-type ?